# attribute error, 'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django

I tried my first django project. The following error occurs

```py
    AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

here is my views.py

```py
    from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
    from django.utils import timezone
    from .models import Post
    from .forms import PostForm

    # Create your views here.

    def post_list(request):
        posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
        return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})

    def post_detail(request, pk):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
        return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})

    def post_new(request):
        form = PostForm()
        return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

here is my urls.py

```py
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views

    urlpatterns =[
        path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
        path('post/<int:pk>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
        path('post/new/', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
    ]
```

and here my forms.py

```py
    from django.forms.models import fields_for_model
    from .models import Post

    class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = Postfields = ('title', 'text',)
            fields = '__all__'
```

when i exe manage.py runserver, i hit that error.
the first error is modelform without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude'
i repair it with added

```py
    fields = '__all__'

in forms.py
```

any idea?

i am using python 3 and django 2.2.4

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a cut-and-paste error.

```
class Meta:
    model = Postfields = ('title', 'text',)
```

That is supposed to be two separate lines:

```
class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ('title', 'text',)
```